# Backwards Method?

Tags: java, matrix, identity

I'm creating a program to create an Identity Matrix - which is pretty easy. But now I need to create the Identity Matrix, but backwards. The result needs to be like so:

> 0 0 1
>
> 0 1 0
>
> 1 0 0

Here is the program I'm using that is creating the Identity Matrix:

```
import java.util.*;
class Lab19Part2 {
    public static int[][] create(int size) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = (i == j) ? 1 : 0;
            return matrix;
    } public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of matrix: ");
            int size=input.nextInt();
            int matrix[][]=create(size);

            for (int i=0 ; i < matrix.length ; i++) { 
            System.out.println();

                for (int j=0 ; j < matrix[i].length ; j++){
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Though it prints out the Identity Matrix like so:

> 1 0 0
>
> 0 1 0
>
> 0 0 1

Question is, how do I make it so it prints out like the first Identity Matrix? I know it has something to do with the for loops but I can't pinpoint it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to simply *print* the identity matrix as the first example or do you want to *create* a matrix that is like your first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change your condition that controls whether the value is 1 or 0:

```
matrix[i][j] = (i + j == size - 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

So that if size is `3`, positions [0][2], [1][1], and [2][0] get 1's.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
matrix[i][j] = (i == j) ? 1 : 0;
```

to

```
matrix[i][j] = (i == size - j - 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this for your identity case:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    matrix[i][i] = 1;
}
```

Then for the other case use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    matrix[i][size - (i+1)] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the brief example how to create it with [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java):

```
Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix(Matrices.asIdentitySource(3)).transpose();

// will create a 3x3 matrix
//
// 0 0 1
// 0 1 0
// 1 0 0
```